# How to show all in one step shipping address, shipping method, payment method billing address and summary?

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, magento2.3.1

I want to make functionality to display all steps on one page with show mode.
So right now default functionality is to 2 steps on the checkout page but I need all in one step.

Comment: check this extension : https://marketplace.magento.com/espl-onepagecheckout.html

Comment: Thanks. But I need to know how to change. as well your extention for 2.0 and 2.1. I want for 2.3.1

Comment: is there any solution for this ?